# how do I inner-join an integer substring of a URL to an integer?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, inner-join

I have two `MySQL` tables in `Joomla`: `categories` and `Menu`.

The field `menu.link` has values like `index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=175`.
The number after the very last equal sign is equal to the field `categories.id`.
I would like to create `INNER JOIN` between two tables so that `categories.id` will be equal to the number in menu.link.

I understand I have to remove all before the number, but how shall I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for a SQL expression that will extract the `id` value from your URL string.  This is always a dicey proposition because it depends on unpredictable details of the format of the URL.

It's a doubly dicey proposition in MySQL because there aren't any regexp functions that return actual string values. They only return true/false. So you need to use non-regexp string processing functions to extract your data.

That being said, let us hack away. This expression will get that number.

```
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(menu.link,'view=category&id=',-1) AS INT) AS cat_id
```

The heart of this string-processing hack is the string `'view=category&id='`. The `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function retrieves everything to the right of that string, and the `CAST` operation takes just the integer.

If the substring is not found, the expression returns zero. That might or might not be what you want. (I said this was dicey!)

So, to perform the join you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT Menu.whatever, 
       categories.whatever
  FROM Menu
  JOIN categories 
    ON categories.id = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(menu.link,'view=category&id=',-1) AS INT)
```

This will perform poorly. But that's probably OK because you won't have tens of thousands of rows in either table.